# Is the closed form of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$ unique?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, analytic-functions

So, I've been studying the power series $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$$
and through algebraic manipulation I've found two ways to get a closed form for it.

The first notices that $$1+xf(x)+x^2f'(x)=f(x)$$ and then proceeds to solve this linear ODE assuming that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm 0}f(x)=1$.

The answer here is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\text{Ei}(x)$, where Ei is defined [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ei%28x%29).

---

The second method notices that $$n!=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^n dt$$ so $$f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (tx)^n dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1-xt}dt$$ which again eventually resolves to $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\text{Ei}(x)$$ (assuming $\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{t} dt=0)$.

It seems that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$ is truly equal to $\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\text{Ei}(x)$, in an analytic continuation kind of sense. However, the series has a radius of convergence equal to $0$, so it shouldn't be possible to fit any function to it. What is going on here? Is it possible to find another function that fits this power series (that doesn't just add a term with power series zero like $e^{-x^{-2}}$)?

Comment: What *closed form* are you talking about? You cannot consider $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$ as a *function* on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ since (as you know) it diverges for $x\neq 0$. (But we can interpret it as a function on [a subset of] [$\mathbb{Q}_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), say, or as a [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series). This is where your *definition*, or at least a clarification, of "closed form" would be welcome.)

Comment: (Related: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126803), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2007863))

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

The solution of
$$1+xf(x)+x^2f'(x)=f(x)$$ is
$$f(x)=c\frac{ e^{-1/x}}{x}+\frac{e^{-1/x} }{x}\text{Ei}\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$$ and, for any value of $c$, $\lim_{x\to 0} \, f(x)=1$ wich makes that we can use $c=0$ for a particular solution.

Effectively
$$\frac{e^{-1/x} }{x}\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$$